# Save and delete image file using parse on heroku and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, heroku, parse-platform

I used heroku with mongoDB for using parse. I deployed parse-server-example and followed all of migration guide.
I want to save PNG file and delete it.
There are some problems T_T

1. When i save image file and seeing on mongoDB, file name is different from i want to save.
2. When i delete it using parse code on Android, fs.chunks and fs.files are left.

For 1st problem code is below

Java : Saving image file

```
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_loading);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] img_write = stream.toByteArray();

ParseFile parseFile = new ParseFile("test.png", img_write);
testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject.put("test", parseFile);
testObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
         @Override
         public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
               Log.e("Write", "SUCCESS");
            } else {
               Log.e("Write", e.getMessage());
            }
         }
});
```

but when i retrieve image it's value of 'test(key)' is '32de5cf8c1b205a8e26367dae3b07ca3_test.png' though i made ParseFile's name for "test.png" and saved it to 'test(key)'.

For 2nd problem code is below

```
query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TestObject");
query.whereContains("test", "test.png");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            objectId = objects.get(0).getObjectId();
            query.getInBackground(objectId, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        object.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    Log.e("Delete", "SUCCESS");
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("Delete", e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                     } else {
                        Log.e("getInBackground", e.getMessage());
                     }
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.e("findInBackground", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

I used 'whereContains' because it's name is '32de5cf8c1b205a8e26367dae3b07ca3_test.png'. And when i delete it 'TestObject' be null but 'fs.files' and 'fs.chunks' are left. I know it is kind of grid file. But is it right that when i delete it, grid files are left?

Please help me for my problems...Thank you for reading my questions.